# Attributes as part of function's type in Clang

Tags: c++, attributes, clang++

Consider the following code.
It's a simplified case of a problem I'm facing.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
__declspec(noreturn) void f();
#else
void f() __attribute__((noreturn));
#endif
[[noreturn]] void g();
void h();

template<typename T>
struct is_func_ptr : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct is_func_ptr<T(*)(Ts...)> : std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_func_ptr<decltype(&f)>::value << '';
    std::cout << is_func_ptr<decltype(&g)>::value << '';
    std::cout << is_func_ptr<decltype(&h)>::value << '';

    return 0;
}
```

GCC and MSVC produce the same output:

> 1 1 1

While Clang (tested on 3.8 and 3.9) in both -fms-extentions and -fno-ms-extensions modes disagrees:

> 0 1 1

Is this behavior intended for non standard attributes? What are the workarounds to properly specialize template on function pointers (so that is exposes return type and parameter types)?